# Win32 Application failure

Tags: c++, windows, api, winapi, codeblocks

My application compiles successfully in visual studio 2019 but when i try to compile this code in Code::Blocks  (Mingw64) it fails.

First, i had this error message  twice:
`error: cannot convert 'const wchar_t*' to 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char*'}`

so i solved the issue by  replacing  this:

```
 AppendMenu(HSUBMENU, MF_STRING, FILE_MENU_EXIT, L"Quit");
 AppendMenu(MENU1,  MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)HSUBMENU, L"FILE");
```

with this:

```
 AppendMenu(HSUBMENU, MF_STRING, FILE_MENU_EXIT, "Quit");
 AppendMenu(MENU1,  MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)HSUBMENU, "FILE");
```

So, this issue was solved ,but had  still another error:

```
error: cannot convert 'LPSTR' {aka 'char*'} to 'LPCWSTR' {aka 'const wchar_t*'} in assignment

wc.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1);
```

I' m stuck at this error

Here below is the original source code  that compiles  successfully  in Visual Studio but fails in Code::Blocks.

I need help please.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "resource.h"



#define FILE_MENU_EXIT 3



LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);







void AddMenue(HWND hwnd)
{
    HMENU MENU1(0), HSUBMENU(0);
    HSUBMENU = CreateMenu();
    MENU1 = CreateMenu();

    AppendMenu(HSUBMENU, MF_STRING, FILE_MENU_EXIT, L"Quit");
    AppendMenu(MENU1,  MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)HSUBMENU, L"FILE");

    SetMenu(hwnd, MENU1);
}






HMENU hmenu;


int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    MSG msg;
    HWND hwnd;
    WNDCLASSW wc;

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"Window";
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = /*(HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+4);*/GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
    wc.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1);

    

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    RegisterClassW(&wc);
    hwnd = CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Window",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 600, 600, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);





    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    // pas necessaire UpdateWindow(hwnd);





    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }


    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {





    switch (msg) {


    

    case WM_CREATE:
        AddMenue(hwnd);
        break;


    case WM_DESTROY:

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }


    return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Try compiling the original code with `-municode`.

Comment: `WNDCLASSA` takes LPCSTR instead of LPCWSTR (in `WNDCLASSW`) for the strings, if you want to use `char*` instead of `wchar_t*` instead.

Comment: Hello,i solved the problem by replacing MAKEINTRESOURCE with MAKEINTRESOURCEW in Code::Blocks

Comment: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 0):

Some of your code is using TCHAR-based APIs without using TCHAR-based strings with them. And some of your code is using Unicode APIs without using Unicode strings with them. This is why you are getting conversion errors.

Specifically...

This code:

```
AppendMenu(HSUBMENU, MF_STRING, FILE_MENU_EXIT, L"Quit");
AppendMenu(MENU1,  MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)HSUBMENU, L"FILE");
```

Needs to be either the following, since `AppendMenu()` is a `TCHAR`-based macro:

```
AppendMenu(HSUBMENU, MF_STRING, FILE_MENU_EXIT, TEXT("Quit"));
AppendMenu(MENU1,  MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)HSUBMENU, TEXT("FILE"));
```

Or this, if you want to use Unicode strings specifically:

```
AppendMenuW(HSUBMENU, MF_STRING, FILE_MENU_EXIT, L"Quit");
AppendMenuW(MENU1,  MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)HSUBMENU, L"FILE");
```

And this code:

```
wc.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1);
```

Needs to be the following, since you are using the Unicode-based `WNDCLASSW` instead of the TCHAR-based `WNDCLASS` (`MAKEINTRESOURCE()` is TCHAR-based):

```
wc.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDR_MENU1);
```

And this code:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {

    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Needs to be the following, since you used the Unicode-based `RegisterClassW()` and `CreateWindowW()` instead of the TCHAR-based `RegisterClass()` and `CreateWindow()`:

```
while (GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {

    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessageW(&msg);
}
```

You really need to pick one encoding scheme and stick with it consistently.  Either use all TCHAR-based APIs, or all Unicode-based APIs. Don't mix them.

Comment: what could  happen if i mix  WNDCLASSW  (unicode )  and   GetMessage(TCHAR) ?

Comment: @Alex if `UNICODE` is defined, `GetMessage()` will map to `GetMessageW()` and all will be fine. But if not, then it will map to `GetMessageA()` and then you'll be mixing a Unicode window with ANSI messages and will likely have bad results